# date histogram of the max of the sum of a field across unique hosts

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a date historgram of the sum of max values for a field across multiple values for another field.  Here's an example of two matching docs:

```
         {
        "_index": "logstash-2014.02.06",
        "_type": "xyz",
        "_id": "HZ_2oaGvQvKWvsOLyYrGrw",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "@version": "1",
           "@timestamp": "2014-02-05T16:01:01.260-08:00",
           "type": "xyz",
           "host": "compute-4.lab.solinea.com",
           "received_at": "2014-02-05 21:01:01 UTC",
           "received_from": "10.10.11.33",
           "total_widgets": 24,
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "logstash-2014.02.06",
        "_type": "xyz",
        "_id": "HZ_2oaGvQvKWvsOLyYrGrx",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "@version": "1",
           "@timestamp": "2014-02-05T16:01:01.260-08:00",
           "type": "xyz",
           "host": "compute-3.lab.solinea.com",
           "received_at": "2014-02-05 21:01:01 UTC",
           "received_from": "10.10.11.32",
           "total_widgets": 13,
        }
     }
```

In this case, I am looking for sum(max(total_widgets)) across unique hosts for this date bucket.  I was trying a datehistogram, but haven't got what I was looking for.  In this example:

```
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "2014-02-05T00:00:00+00:00",
            "lte": "2014-03-05T00:00:00+00:00"
         }
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "total_widgets_facet": {
         "date_histogram": {
            "key_field": "@timestamp",
            "value_field": "total_widgets",
            "interval": "hour"
         },
         "facet_filter": {
            "term": {
               "type": "xyz"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get back a max value of 24, but I haven't quite got my head around how to structure the query and facet so that I am looking at the sum of the max of "total_widgets" across all unique hosts for a time bucket.

I definitely appreciate any suggestions...

Comment: have you looked into [ES 1.0 aggregation capabilities](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations.html)? Your case might be easier to solve with that new feature.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Now that you mention it, I did see that page a little while ago and thought it was interesting and applicable.  I'm definitely looking forward to 1.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't find an efficient way to do this with Elasticsearch 0.90.x, but the following query is an example of how to use aggregations in 1.0.x to achieve the desired results:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                     "from": "2014-02-07T00:00:00.000-00:00",
                     "to": "2014-02-07T23:59:59.999-00:00"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "term": {
                  "type": "xyz"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "events_by_host": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "host.raw"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "events_by_date": {
               "date_histogram": {
                  "field": "@timestamp",
                  "interval": "hour"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "max_total_widgets": {
                     "max": {
                        "field": "total_widgets"
                     }
                  },
                  "avg_total_widgets": {
                     "avg": {
                        "field": "total_widgets"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I wrote a blog post on the topic here:  [Elasticsearch Aggs Save the Day](http://www.solinea.com/blog/elasticsearch-aggs-save-the-day)